# A symmetric embedding of manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, symmetry

Assume that $M$ is  a manifold.

Is there an embedding of $M$ in  some $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that the image of  $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is invariant under each reflection $(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots x_{i},\ldots,x_{n}) \mapsto (x_{1},x_{2},\ldots , -x_{i},\ldots,x_{n})$, for all $i\in \{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$?

Comment: Why can't you simply embed $M$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ in any way possible  and then embed the $\mathbb{R}^m$ symmetrically into $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$?

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill the  natural embedding of $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$ is  a  symmetric embedding, but obviously it does not solve the main question of this post.yes?,

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  I was thinking of only one reflection.

Comment: This would imply first of all that $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^n$ acts on $M$ in a nontrivial way. More precisely, if the $i$-th of the $n$ generators acts trivially, then the embedding factors through $\mathbb R^{n-1}$, where the $i$-th coordinate is missing. If a generator acts nontrivially, it has to reverse orientation. If $M$ was compact and orientable, this has consequences for the cohomology ring (e.g., $M$ cannot be an even-dimensional Kähler manifold), and all the Pontryagin numbers would have to vanish. On the other hand, for orientable compact surfaces, such embeddings obviously exist.

Comment: @SebastianGoette  thank you for your very interesting comment. is it obvious that the restriction of a reflection to M is either identity or orientation reversing?Moreover may you elaborate  about  orientable compact surface?Moreover, i guess that a  compact  manifold with fixed point property, does not admit such symmetric embedding. do you think that my guess is true?

Comment: In the previous comment i  mean;.....(a closed compact  manifold with fixed point property....).

Comment: Dear Ali, I forgot to assume that $M$ is connected. Otherwise, you could embed a connected component to $(0,\infty)^n$ and add $2^n-1$ mirror images. If $M$ is connected, then each generator $\gamma_i$ must have a fixed point $x$ (i.e., $x\in M$ with $x_i=0$). If $\gamma_i$ acts trivially on $T_xM$, it acts trivially on $M$. Otherwise, the one-dimensional $(-1)$-eigenspace of $\gamma_i$ will lie inside $T_xM$. In this case, $\gamma_i$ reverses orientation as claimed.

Comment: $S^2\subset\mathbb R^3$ is easy. To embed a compact orientable surface of genus $g>0$ into $\mathbb R^3$, assume the centers of its "holes" are at $(g-1,0,0),(g-3,0,0),\dots, (1-g,0,0)$, and the circles in the $xy$-plane of radius $1/2$ around these centers are contained in $M$. Now, build the rest of $M$ as symmetrically around these circles as possible.

Comment: @SebastianGoette: do you mean that M cannot be a $4k$-dimensional Kähler manifold?

Comment: @TomChurch I was a bit too quick. If $\omega$ is the Kähler form, then $\gamma_i^*\omega=\pm\omega$ is impossible because then $\gamma_i^*\omega^{2k}=\omega^{2k}$, but $\gamma_i$ reverses orientation. But $\gamma_i^*\omega$ is a Kähler form, too, so we have at most hyperkähler holonomy (or maybe a symmetric space?). So I was wrong: at least $T^{4k}$ admits such an embedding. However, $K3$ does not because its signature is nonzero (which is a Pontryagin number by Hirzebruch's theorem). So what about higher dimensional hyperkähler manifolds and Kähler symmetric spaces?

Comment: @SebastianGoette  thanks again for your very helpful comments.

Comment: @TomChurch Having thought about hyperkähler manifolds: if there is an $S^2$ worth of Kähler forms, then $\gamma_i^*$ cannot act linearly on those without fixing one of them or mapping it to its antipode. So, $M$ cannot be an irreducible, nonflat hyperkähler manifold.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. There exist closed manifolds which do not admit any compact group actions, in particular, no $Z_2$ actions. For example, Shultz showed in ["Group actions on hypertoral manifolds. II."](https://eudml.org/doc/152358) that in  dimensions $\ge 4$ every oriented cobordism class contains such a manifold.